# Multidimensional Array Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to loop through this multidimensional array in the view of blade template but unable to get the elements. I tried using nested foreach but that doesn't work. I'm unsure what else to do. Please help

```
Array
(
[2] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[3] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ActivityID] => 1
                        [WaiverID] => 3
                        [ProgramID] => 1
                        [ActivityName] => Waiver3 Activity 1
                        [WaiverName] => Waiver 3
                        [ID] => 3
                        [WaiverDescription] => 
                        [ProgramID] => 1
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ActivityID] => 2
                        [WaiverID] => 3
                        [ProgramID] => 1
                        [ActivityName] => Waiver3 Activity 2
                        [WaiverName] => Waiver 3
                        [ID] => 3
                        [WaiverDescription] => 
                        [ProgramID] => 1
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ActivityID] => 3
                        [WaiverID] => 3
                        [ProgramID] => 1
                        [ActivityName] => Waiver3 Activity 3
                        [WaiverName] => Waiver 3
                        [ID] => 3
                        [WaiverDescription] => 
                        [ProgramID] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

When I do a foreach like this

```
@foreach ($waiverActivityforTable as$waiverActivityforTableValue)           
    {{ $waiverActivityforTableValue }}
@endforeach
```

I get:

```
[] [] [{"ActivityID":1,"WaiverID":3,"PHAProgramID":1,"ActivityName":"Waiver3 
Activity 1","HCVWaiverName":"Waiver 
3","ID":3,"HCVWaiverDescription":null,"phaProgramID":1},
{"ActivityID":2,"WaiverID":3,"PHAProgramID":1,"ActivityName":"Waiver3 
Activity 2","HCVWaiverName":"Waiver 
3","ID":3,"HCVWaiverDescription":null,"phaProgramID":1},
{"ActivityID":3,"WaiverID":3,"PHAProgramID":1,"ActivityName":"Waiver3 
Activity 3","HCVWaiverName":"Waiver 
3","ID":3,"HCVWaiverDescription":null,"phaProgramID":1}]
```

Tired nested foreach:
I tried:

```
    @foreach ($waiverActivityforTable as $waiverActivityforTableValue)
        @foreach ($waiverActivityforTableValue as $test)
            {{ $test }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

but I get an error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Please show how are you getting the data and what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I have created a multidimensional array in the controller and I now need to access and display it in the view. Added some edits for clarification

Comment: You need nested loops to iterate over all items of a multi-dimensional array. `$waiverActivityforTableValue` contains another array of the objects.

Comment: I did try a nested foreach but I get an error. I've added it above

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the nested multidimensional array might be empty, check for it before echoing it out

```
@if(is_array($waiverActivityforTable)
     @foreach ($waiverActivityforTable as $waiverActivityforTableValue)
      @endif
          @if(is_array($waiverActivityforTableValue)
            @foreach ($waiverActivityforTableValue as $test)
             @endif
              @isset($test)
                {{ $test }}
                 @endisset
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
```

The specific check for `is_array` and `isset` might be different, based on your data.

That being said, the multidimensional array you are trying to parse, should have been initialized in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collection::toArray` method to convert the collection into a plain PHP array:

```
 @foreach ($waiverActivityforTable->toArray() as $waiverActivityforTableValue)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
    @foreach ($waiverActivityforTableValue as $test)
        {{ $test }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```